# The same logic on an array is producing different results

Tags: c++, arrays

This is the function:

```
void print(int arr[], int size)
{
    int* count = new int [size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    count[arr[i]]++;
    cout << count[arr[i]] << endl;
    }
}
```

When I call (in my main) `print(arr, sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]))` where `a = {4, 2, 4, 5, 2, 3}`, I would get the updated count of each number in the array.
Now, let's say I want to do something very similar to this but in my `int main()`:

```
int* my_arr = new int[10];
my_arr[1]++;
cout << "my_arr[1] = " << my_arr[1];
```

The last statement prints something like 15799121, which I assume is the memory address of `my_arr[1]`.
How is this not the same in `print()`? Shouldn't `cout << count[arr[i]] << endl;` produce the same result?

Comment: `count[arr[i]]++;` is undefined behavior, due to reading uninitialized memory. None of the elements in array `count` is initialized. Did you mean to initialize all of them to `0`?

Comment: Ask yourself: What value is in `my_arr[1]` when you don't put anything in there to begin with.

Comment: @NathanOliver I know, but in ```print()```, it seems like when I do ```count[arr[i]]++``` the elements in count are initializing themselves to zero. I'm puzzled.

Comment: @icecream2727 "_I know, but in `print()`, it seems like when I do `count[arr[i]]++` the elements are initializing themselves to zero. I'm puzzled._" That is the definition of undefined behavior: literally any possible behavior is expected: the elements can contain all zeros; the elements can contain random values; the elements could contain all zeros, unless you are demoing your application; your hard drive can be formatted upon reading the uninitialized array elements. If you want those elements initialized to a particular value: do so, instead of relying on undefined behavior.

Comment: `int* my_arr = new int[10];` why are you using dynamic allocation? Why not a plain `std::array<int, 10> my_arr;` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For [default initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization),

> otherwise, nothing is done: the objects with automatic storage duration (and their subobjects) are initialized to indeterminate values.

That means given `new int [size]`, the elements of the array are initialized to indeterminate values, use of these values leads to [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), means anything is possible.

You might want [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), i.e. `new int [size]()`; all the elements would be initialized to `0` exactly.

Comment: Then how is ```cout << count[arr[i]] << endl;``` printing their actual counts as if they were initialized automatically (to zero) with ```count[arr[i]]++```?

Comment: @icecream2727 UB means anything is possible, on which you shouldn't depend.

Comment: @icecream2727 The array could contain any value. Zero is a value. It might have zero, or it might not.

Comment: @icecream2727 -- Read the answer carefully, especially the last two words of the highlighted section:  `... are initialized to **indeterminate values**`.  Indeterminate does not mean "not 0".  A `0` is just as indeterminate as `7623432` or `-423432423`.

Comment: Turn on your compilers optimizer and the value *probably* won't be zero any more. You have UB, you broke the rules of the language, your program has no well defined meaning and you can get *any* result - including exactly what you expect, nothing at all, a crash, the compiler generating code to format your harddrive; literally *anything* is valid when UB is involved.